# jQuery, how to make a on click function work with array to toggle divs based on id?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Here's my code:

```
 foreach($rows as $row)
   {
    echo '<div class="div-that-toggles-other-div" id="' . $row['unique_id'] .'">';
    }

    foreach($rows as $row)
    {
      echo '<div class="div-to-be-toggled" id="uid-' . $row['unique_id'] .'">';
     }
```

The jQuery i've used to toggle the div before wont work when im printing an array of divs where i want only the specific id to open specific div.

```
$(".div-that-toggles-other-div").click(function () {
            $(".div-to-be-toggled").slideToggle(1000);
        });
```

how can i make it toggle depending on id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help you.

```
$(function(){
   $(".div-that-toggles-other-div").click(function () {
        var divId = $(this).attr('id');
        $("#uid-"+divId).slideToggle(1000);
    });
});
```